# Get system installation date programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, console-application, macos-sierra

I am trying to get the system installation date by running a console app.
The only way I know how to do this is by parsing the `/var/log/install.log` file for the latest string containing `OSInstaller` & `Install Complete` items.

Is there a handy system API I am missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So in case, someone finds this useful.

## Swift 3.0

### SOLUTION 1

Initially I parsed `/var/log/install.log` file to get date string:

```
    // To get OS installation date we'll need to check system log file and find entry which contains installation date
var systemDates : String? = nil
do {
    let fullSystemLog = try NSString(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/var/log/install.log"), encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    let entries = fullSystemLog.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    //Filter to get only entries about OS installation
    let filtered = entries.filter{ entry in
        return entry.contains("OSInstaller") && entry.contains("Install Complete") //Markers telling that OS was installed
    }

    var latestMention = ""
    if filtered.count > 0 {
        //If 1 or more entries found we'll pick last one
        latestMention = filtered.last!
    }
    else if entries.count > 0 {
        //If there are 0 mentions of OS installation - we'll use first entry in logs
        latestMention = entries.first!
    }

    //parse picked entry for date
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: ".+:[0-9]{2}", options: [])
        let nsString = latestMention as NSString
        let results = regex.matches(in: latestMention,
                                    options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
        let actualDateSubstrings = results.map { nsString.substring(with: $0.range)}

        if let dateStringFromMention = actualDateSubstrings.first {

            systemDates = dateStringFromMention
        }
        else {
            systemDates = "<Error: no date results>"
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        systemDates = "<Error: invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)>"
    }
} 
catch {
    systemDates = "<Error: system log file not found>"
}

print("\tSYSTEM INSTALLED: \(systemDates)")
```

## SOLUTION 2

The second solution appears much simpler. Look into the `InstallDate` field of `/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.BaseSystemResources.plist`:

```
let systemDates = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: "/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.BaseSystemResources.plist")

print("\tSYSTEM INSTALLED: \(systemDates?["InstallDate"])")
```

Comment: The second solution is returning nil.

Answer (score 1):

As a suggestion for exploration **only**:

You could try looking at the files `/System/Library/Receipts`.

You will probably see a `com.apple.pkg.BaseSystemResources.plist` file, its modification date may tell you when the OS was installed.

There are also `com.apple.pkg.update.os.*.plist` files for updates, again look at the modification dates and maybe parse the wildcard (`*`) bit if you can determined a naming convention.

HTH, Happy Hunting!

Comment: I quickly found date string on /System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.BaseSystemResources.p‌​list. This is much faster than parsing few thousand line log. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
system_profiler SPInstallHistoryDataType | grep macOS -A 4
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**